Como importar um pacote java dentro do POM.xml?
Estou trabalhando em testes de contrato usando o Pact em um aplicativo Java com Quarkus. No entanto, estou enfrentando uma dificuldade: preciso modificar as solicitações antes de enviá-las, já que a autenticação é necessária para o endpoint. Encontrei uma solução na documentação que envolve o envio de uma autorização em cada solicitação, mas o token tem um período de expiração. Isso significa que a solução atual não é ideal, pois tenho que gerar e substituir manualmente o token no arquivo pom.xml sempre que executar os testes.
Para resolver esse problema, encontrei um código que, téoricamente permite importar um pacote no pom.xml, o qual contém uma classe com um método para retornar o token. No entanto, ao tentar verificar o contrato, a solicitação falha porque não consegue resolver a classe.
Abaixo é a estrutura de pastas que tenho no projeto, note dentro da estrutura tenho um arquivo chamado OAuthTokenRequest.java, ele é o responsável por gerar o token necessário para a requisição. Ao compilar usando o comando ./mvnw compile quarkus:dev, o classpah é atualizado e a partir dai temos o arquivo OAuthTokenRequest.class que é o que tento importar dentro do pom.xml.
.
├── ...
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── docker
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── ...
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           ├── com
│           │   └── company
│           │       ├── pact
│           │       │   ├── README.MD
│           │       │   ├── consumer
│           │       │   │   └── ContractConsumerTest.java
│           │       │   └── provider
│           │       │       └── ContractProviderTest.java
│           │       └── resources
│           │           └── ...
│           └── it
│               └── util
│                   ├── OAuthConfig.java
│                   ├── OAuthTokenRequest.java
│                   └── OAuthTokenRequestTest.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   └── ...
    └── test-classes
        ├── com
        │   └── company
        │       ├── pact
        │       │   ├── README.MD
        │       │   ├── consumer
        │       │   │   └── ContractConsumerTest.class
        │       │   └── provider
        │       │       └── ContractProviderTest.class
        │       └── resources
        │           └── ...
        └── it
            └── util
                ├── OAuthConfig.class
                ├── OAuthTokenRequest.class
                └── OAuthTokenRequestTest.class

Agora, abaixo temos o trecho do código com a "tentativa" de importar o método dentro da classe para gerar o token e utilizar na aplicação.
<plugin>
        <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <serviceProviders>
            <serviceProvider>
              <name>ConnectorsProvider</name>
              <requestFilter>
                // This is a Groovy script that adds an Authorization header to each request
                import it.util.OAuthTokenRequest
                String authHeader = "Bearer " + new OAuthTokenRequest.getToken()
                request.addHeader('Authorization', authHeader)
              </requestFilter>
              <protocol>https</protocol>
              <host>gateway.production.io</host>
              <port>443</port>
            </serviceProvider>
          </serviceProviders>
          <pactDirectory>target/pacts</pactDirectory>
          <pactBrokerUrl>http://localhost:9292</pactBrokerUrl>
          <pactBrokerUsername>pactBrokerUsername</pactBrokerUsername>
          <pactBrokerPassword>pactBrokerPassword</pactBrokerPassword>
          <trimSnapshot>true</trimSnapshot>
          <configuration>
            <pact.verifier.publishResults>true</pact.verifier.publishResults>
          </configuration>
        </configuration>
</plugin>

Um detalhe sobre esse trecho é que quando utilizo algo o token explicito, funciona perfeitamente.
Tentei reescrever de outras formas como:
<requestFilter>
                // This is a Groovy script that adds an Authorization header to each request
                import it.util
                String authHeader = "Bearer " + new OAuthTokenRequest.getToken()
                request.addHeader('Authorization', authHeader)
</requestFilter>

Ou
<requestFilter>
                // This is a Groovy script that adds an Authorization header to each request
                import it.util
                request.addHeader('Authorization', OAuthTokenRequest.getToken())
</requestFilter>

Mas acabo recebendo um erro parecido:
    Request Failed - startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class it.util.OAuthTokenRequest
 @ line 3, column 17.
                   import it.util.OAuthTokenRequest
                   ^

1 error

Agradeço qualquer ajuda que você possa oferecer.
